# swap image, change width and height

Tags: jquery, css, image, swap

I have a div, and in this div is an image.
What I have done now is that the image has a width of 100%.
I want if I swap the image with another image that for instance has a bigger height than the div. I want the height to be 100% instead of the width. I do not want to make changes to the CSS, I want that these changes happen when I swap the image. Is this possible?

HTML

```
<div id="i3-box1">
    <img id="i3-logo" src="images/logo.png">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#i3-logo{width: 100%;}
```

JQuery

```
$("#i3-logo").attr("src", "images/logo2.png");
```

I use JQuery to swap the image because this action is for more than 1 HTML.

Comment: `$("#i3-logo").attr("src", "images/logo2.png").height('100%');`

Comment: You have to change `height` css with jquery.

Comment: yea but depending on the image it has to change, so I dont know if logo3 or logo4 etc. are bigger in witdh or in height than the div. It can be any image. (it should automaticly change without changing to code)

Comment: It will adjust automatically, no need to get height of new image.

Comment: aah sorry just understood what you guys where saying, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.height(value)`](http://api.jquery.com/height/#height2) or [`.css( propertyName, value )`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) method

```
$("#i3-logo").attr("src", "images/logo2.png").height('100%');
```

OR

```
$("#i3-logo").attr("src", "images/logo2.png").css('height', '100%');
```

Comment: Thank you, I now only have to change the height to width or visa versa in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set the outer DIV height same as the loaded logo height.

I hope this helps:

```
$('#i3-box1').height($('#i3-logo').height());
```

it need to be executed after each time the new img loads.